# Spring boot security for specific page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Lets say i have a route to "/editprofile/{userId}", the only person that can send requests to this route is the account with the same user id.
For example "/editprofile/1" can be accesed by the user with user id 1 but not by the user with user id 2 and vice versa. How can i implement this security in spring. Is there a "dynamic" way with ant matchers, do i have to do a manual get current user and check if his id is the same as the userId. Whats the best way to go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the route is the same, you can just use the preAuthorize annotation and check whether the current logged in user id is the same as the route id given.
Look into SpEL for that matter.

Comment: or you do it with a configuration. that has the advantage, that you do not have to declare the preAuthorized on each method.https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/